# Select box's selectedIndex being set to -1 when option removed in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have two select boxes (available products and selected products). The use moves the items from one listbox to another. This works fine but in IE when i do a .remove(selectedIndex) (Javascript) on the option they selected the selectedIndex of that box gets set to -1. I want the listbox to remain in the same position but just remove the product they selected.

I have also tried

listbox.options[iProductIndex] = null;

This behaves the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Sam

Comment: When you say you "want the listbox to remain in the same position but just remove the product they selected", do you mean that the item before or after the one you've removed should be selected?

Comment: Neither should be selected, i dont want a selectedIndex (this displays additional info which would confuse the user). I just want the top visible item in the multiselect to be the same. I dont want it to jump back to the start. Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, that's clearer. I don't have an easy answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the old selectedIndex in a variable then change it back once the removal process is complete:

```
var oldSelectedIndex = obj.selectedIndex;
obj.remove(oldSelectedIndex);
obj.selectedIndex = oldSelectedIndex;
```

You should also make sure that `oldSelectedIndex` is not out of bounds after you remove one item, but the above snippet was to get the idea across.

Comment: Same problem as above, the listbox is a multiselect and it doesnt guarantee they selected the top item, therfore the items above the one selected are pushed up and not visible by the user.